# Ionic /Cordova View position issue during a phone call or internet connection shared

Tags: ios, cordova, google-maps-api-3, ionic3

I have this issue only when I shared my phone internet connection on my iphone.
I get this blue bar on top of the screen which moves everything down a little bit. Only the googlemap View is not moving down a bit, and this creates a white space between the map and the bottom tabbar.

I have the same behavior during a phone call (green bar on top)

Any Idea how to prevent and correct this ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Prevent you cant, correct you should. If you are using autolayout , the top of the google map view or container or whatever, should be aligned with bottom of `topLayOutGuide`.

If you are not using Autolayout, you can listen to the `UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarFrameNotification`, and change the frame of the google map view or container or whatever.

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot find topLayOutGuide in IONIC framework. Is there a way to get the googlemap view and linked it to the top bar ?

Comment: What are you using, .xibs or stryboard?

Comment: I only use XCode to compile the code generated by Ionic / cordova ( https://ionicframework.com/docs ). then I do not use storyboards